# Notebook to run on batches of files

Tags: notebooks, memory

I have a notebook that Imports files from a folder and processes and stores outputs into another folder.

It works well with small number of files, however, when there's a large number of input files, it crashes halfway.

Just to be clear, I'm using the code below to import all my data

```
allData = Table[Import[...],{i,1,ndatasets}]
```

Following this, the variable allData is manipulated on.

I have a feeling allData may be too big when the number of files imported is large.

Is there a way to run the notebook in batches, over say, 10 or so files at a time?

Or is there another solution instead of using big variables like allData? In other programming languages, I would use a FOR loop over datasets, and smaller variables that can be "cleared" within my loop.

Comment: If you do not need to have the entire dataset in memory, you can still use `Do` to process files one by one. `Do` in Mathematica is comparate for `for` or `foreach` in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Why feel when you can measure?

I usually approach this problem through a `Do[]` loop.  I also have the function `MemorySummary[]` defined as

```
MemorySummary[]:=Print["Memory currently in use : ",MemoryInUse[]/1024.^2, "Mb, Maximum memory used in session : ",MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024.^2, "Mb"]
```

One suggestion would be to preallocate your `allData` array.  You know its length as `ndatasets`.  What else do you know about it?  Does each file have the same number of variables?

With this in mind, one basic algorithm looks like

```
MemorySummary[];
alldata = Range@ndatasets;
Do[
 tmpdata = Import[dataset[[jf]], "table"];
 (* here we perform any cleaning or other data manipulation that might be required on the tmpdata array *)
 alldata[[jf]] = tmpdata;
 (* should memory be an issue, here is where you'd Clear[] or Remove[] if you need to *)
 Print[DateString[], ": File "<>ToString@jf<>" using "<>MemorySummary[]],
 {jf, ndatasets}
];
```

so we get time taken to read each data set as well as the memory in use.

Extension to parallel processing is fairly straightforward through either `ParallelDo[]` or manually through `Do[]` with optional step if you choose.

Your mileage may vary.